# Action Bar Menu Items not Working

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have created an action bar with two Menu Items. When I try using an intent for the buttons they don't work. When click on the menu item, web page will be loaded.How to do it.

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Camera"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id= "@+id/emoticons"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_emoticons"
        android:title="Emoticon"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.camera:
            startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/")));

            return true;
        case R.id.emoticons:
            startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/")));
            return true; 

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @developerknownasInsane by button OP means, menu Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is overridden with wrong name (thus is not overridden but is a different method) and thus is not called by menu.

```
public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

Should be starting with small "o"

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

You should use Override annotation to avoid such mistakes.